# Change html text when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help because i don't know how to change the text more than one time:

This is my span:

```
<span  id="demo" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()"><b> + </b></span>
```

And this is my `.js` file

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<b> - </b>";
}
```

In my `span` when i click in `+` it will change for `-` but if i click again it wont change to `+` how can i make that happend?

I need this because if there is the `+` means that if you click my `div` will show up, and it will change to `-` but if i click again my `div` will hide but the `-` stays there and i need to change it to `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to change the `innerHTML`(As you are not updating HTML but text), just select `b` element using `querySelector` and change the [**`textContent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of it based on conditions([`Conditional (ternary) Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)).

> *The `Node.textContent` property represents the text content of a node and its descendants.*

```js
function myFunction() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("demo").querySelector('b');
  elem.textContent = elem.textContent == ' - ' ? ' + ' : ' - ';
}
```

```html
<span id="demo" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()"><b> + </b></span>
```

Comment: @MarUSPT, I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 3):

### With plain Javascript :

```js
function myFunction() {
        var el = document.getElementById("demo");
        if (el.innerHTML == "<b> - </b>")
            el.innerHTML = "<b> + </b>";
        else
            el.innerHTML = "<b> - </b>";
    }
```

```html
<span  id="demo" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()"><b> + </b></span>
```

- If you're good with [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) :

  ```
  function myFunction() {
      var inner = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
      inner = "<b>" + (inner == "<b> + </b>" ? "-" : "+") + "</b>";
  }
  ```
- Though the cleanest way is Rayon's, using both [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) :

  ```
  function myFunction() {
      var el = document.getElementById("demo").querySelector('b');
      elem.textContent = elem.textContent == ' - ' ? ' + ' : ' - ';
  }
  ```

  Check [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054118/4864023) for more details about it.

---

### With jQuery :

Since you put the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag, I'll add the jQuery way :

```js
$('#demo').click(function(){
    if ($(this).find('b').text() == "-")
        $(this).find('b').text("+");
    else
        $(this).find('b').text("-");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span  id="demo" style="cursor: pointer;"><b> + </b></span>
```

- With [ternary operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) :

  ```
  $('#demo').click(function(){
      $(this).find('b').text($(this).find('b').text() == "-" ? "+" : "-")
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

you may try this:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=="<b>-</b>")?"<b>+</b>":"<b>-</b>";
}
```

```html
<span  id="demo" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()"><b> + </b></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
var demoEl = document.getElementById("demo");
function myFunction() {
  if (demoEl.innerHTML == "<b> + </b>"){
    demoEl.innerHTML = "<b> - </b>";
  } else {
    demoEl.innerHTML = "<b> + </b>";
  }
}
```

```html
<span  id="demo" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()"><b> + </b></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var val = $("#txt").text();
  var newVal = val == "+" ? "-" : "+";
  $("#txt").text(newVal);
  $("#myContent").slideToggle(500);
}
```

```css
div#myContent{
  display:none;
 border : 2px red solid;
  padding : 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="demo" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="myFunction()"><b> <span id="txt">+</span> 
</b>
</span>
<div id="myContent">Here goes my Content</div>
```